# Sublime search with * (search multiple partials)

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to find the result -> **'the_red_cat'** using sublime search. I have enabled the regex but cannot figure out how to get the result I need.

I would like to search something along the line of ***the*ca*** but it does not seem to yield any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `.*the.*ca.*` finds the whole lines that contain the text. Searching for any number of characters with regex is done with `.*`.